# How can i refer QuotelineItem fields from Quote Object?

Tags: formula-field, quote, quotelineitem

Can formula field on Quote obj solve my use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't build formulas on child objects. You could use a trigger or rollup summary field to transfer the information up to the quote, which you could then reference in a formula.